# Decimal to binary for large number (>2253483438943167)

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net application that goes through a series of processes to decode a string, one problem with this is that I have found a function that converts from binary to decimal for any number, but I cannot find a function that will convert a supplied number (in string format) into a binary string. For reference, the binary to decimal conversion function is below:

```
Public Function baseconv(d As String)
    Dim N As Long
    Dim Res As Long
    For N = Len(d) To 1 Step -1
        Res = Res + ((2 ^ (Len(d) - N)) * CLng(Mid(d, N, 1)))
    Next N
    Return Str(Res)
End Function
```

Comment: can the number be held inside, say, a 64 bit integer ?

Comment: The number is originally a string of digits, if I could convert it to a 64 bit integer and convert it to binary that way it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do if the number is less than 16*1e18  <-> can hold in a Uint64 :
1) store the number inside an unsigned 64 bits integer : num.
2) then just loop on each bit to test it :

```
 mask = 1<<63
 do
     if ( num AND mask ) then ->> push("1")
     else ->> push("0")
     mask = mask >> 1
 until mask = 0
```

(where push builds the output with a string concatenation, or, if performance matters, a StringBuilder, or it can be a stream,... )

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(2253483438943167 * 5, 2))
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

Comment: @Lugia101101, this code compile and run perfectly in .net 4.0, which version do you use and which number?

Comment: I think it may be due to me having to convert from string to integer.

Comment: @Lugia101101, you want to convert the string 1101010010101010101010101010 to int? this will be impossible

Comment: No, I need to convert a decimal string to a binary string.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` class like this:

```
Dim d As String
d = "2253483438943167"

Dim bi As BigInteger
bi = BigInteger.Parse(d)

Dim ba() As Byte
ba = bi.ToByteArray()

Dim s As String
Dim N As Long

Dim pad as Char
pad = "0"c

For N = Len(ba) To 1 Step -1
    s = s + Convert.ToString(ba(N)).PadLeft(8, pad)  
Next N
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    Dim foo As BigInteger = Long.MaxValue
    foo += Long.MaxValue
    foo += 2
    Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each b As Byte In foo.ToByteArray.Reverse
        s.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c))
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine(s.ToString.TrimStart("0"c))
    '10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```